# Drag and Drop Resize drop zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

Using Jquery to drag and drop but on the drag start I re-size the drop DIV. However when dragging the drop item towards the DIV it appears to only use the previous drop-zone size as the space.

Any way to fix this?

```
  $('.dragme').draggable({
    revert: true,
    cursor: 'move',
    start: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#drop-box').animate({height: '300px' }, 250);
  },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the event listener?

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {} );
```